# Unit Testing of a model in Play Framework 2.3

Tags: unit-testing, playframework, playframework-2.0, junit4, ebean

We recently moved from Play Framework 2.1 to 2.3 and some unit test stops working.

In this particular unit test, I'm using an object that extends Model from ebean. I make sure not to use any function from ebean (like `find()`, `save()` or `update()`).

Unfortunately, just by creating my object, I get an exception because it try to initiate the `Model.Finder` member, which I'm pretty sure it wasn't doing before the migration. How can I overcome this?

My setUp function that throw exception on the `new` call.

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {  
    SignageScheduleEntry allTheTimeSchedule = new SignageScheduleEntry();
}
```

My object itself, it fails on the new Model.Finder when debugging the unit test:

```
public static Model.Finder<Long,SignageScheduleEntry> find = new Model.Finder<>(Long.class, SignageScheduleEntry.class);

    public SignageScheduleEntry() throws InvalidPeriodException {   
        ....
    }
```

In brief, I want to use my object without the ebean crap in my unit test like any object in any unit test. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown here:https://github.com/jamesward/play2torial/blob/master/JAVA.md#create-a-model

You will need to create a "fakeApplication" like so:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static play.test.Helpers.fakeApplication;
import static play.test.Helpers.running;

import static org.fest.assertions.Assertions.assertThat;

import models.Task;

public class TaskTest {

    @Test
    public void create() {
        running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Task task = new Task();
                task.contents = "Write a test";
                task.save();
                assertThat(task.id).isNotNull();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

If that doesn't work, or if that's not what you're looking for, another approach is more complex and convoluted from the Play Java docs:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaTest#Unit-testing-models

You basically have to create a wrapper for the Model, and mock out the wrapper in the unit tests.

Comment: I guess creating a fake application must be slow as hell... Play framework is definitely lagging behind other framework related to unit testing and TDD in general... Anyway, I don't have the choice right now! Thanks